# Two forever instances with upstart

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, upstart, forever

I'm trying to start two forever instances but it doesn't work

```
#Start node@4040 node@5050 con forever

description "node@4040 node@5050"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown


script
    cd /var/node/
    exec forever start -l /var/node/logs/for5050.log -o /var/node/logs/out5050.log -e /var/node/logs/err5050.log app.js 5050
    exec forever start -l /var/node/logs/for4040.log -o /var/node/logs/out4040.log -e /var/node/logs/err4040.log app.js 4040
end script
```

What's the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process exec must be in its own conf file. So in your case, you need to create 2 upstart conf files for each of your nodejs programs. The same conf file cannot run multiple exec commands.

Comment: Since forever runs as a daemon I believe you will also need to add:
`expect fork`
See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#exec for the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving them different names, e.g app1.js and app2.js

Comment: Yes, but when I reboot the computer and the two instances are supposed to start, just one starts